# Error when testing Firestore online with Jest: "Auth error:TypeError: fetch is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to test Cloud Firestore with Jest, but have the following error.

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require("../../../config/YOUR-PROJECT-NAME-firebase-adminsdk-XXXX-XXXXXX.json");

// const myfirestore: any = new MyFireStore()

describe('MyFirestore', () =>{
  it('getDocument', async () => {
    
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: "https://unittest-dfb64.firebaseio.com"
    });

    let result = false
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const collectionRef = db.collection('test')
    const docRef = collectionRef.doc('testDoc')
    const getDoc = await docRef.get()
    if (getDoc && getDoc.exists) {
      result = getDoc.data()
    }

    expect(result).toEqual('testdata')
  }, 100000)
```

"Auth error:TypeError: fetch is not a function".

[image]
<sub>(source: [goodpic.com](https://www.goodpic.com/app/uploads/2019/05/Screenshot-2019-05-25-at-00.01.01.png))</sub>

I googled a lot but could not find any hint about this error.
What is the proper way to access to the Firestore data inside Jest test?
Thank you so much for your help in advance.

The full code is uploaded here.

https://github.com/goodpic/firebase-graphql-boilerplate

I checked and tried these docs but could not figure out what is the root of this error.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/test/test.online.js
https://gist.github.com/starhoshi/21d1fb870d485a95c86fe93cfe1ac240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed at firebase-admin 8.1.0

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/512#issuecomment-503392508

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the root of the cause of this issue. The issue was caused by an incompatibility between jest and the gaxios project.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/512#issuecomment-487218219

As a workaround of the issue, I could solve by downgrading gaxios to 1.8.3 as explained in the comment.

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^7.3.0",
    "gaxios": "1.8.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "**/gaxios": "1.8.3"
  },
```